# ¿Cómo pintar la información que me llega de un php en un componente html de angular?

Tags: php, html, angular, phpmyadmin

Service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Users } from '../alumnos';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) 
export class ApiService {


  url = 'http://localhost:5050/php/'; // disponer de el url de su servidor que tiene los archivos PHP
  Users : Users;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  Login(login) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}getinfo.php`, JSON.stringify(login));
  }
  RecibirInfo(alumno) {
    this.Users = alumno;
  }
  Register(register) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}register.php`, JSON.stringify(register));
  }
  Registerprof(register) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}registerprofesor.php`, JSON.stringify(register));
  }
  recojer(){
    return this.Users;
  }
}
```

Home.component.ts(donde quiero enseñar mi informacion):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "../userservice/api.service";
import { Users } from '../alumnos';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  Users: Users;

  constructor(public ApiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Users = this.ApiService.recojer();
    console.log(this.Users.Pass);
  }
}
```

objeto que asocio con el la información que me llega: alumno.ts

```
export class Users {
    constructor(
    public Id: number,
    public Nick : string,
    public Pass : string,
    public Email? : string,
    public Nombre? : string,
    public Apellidos? : string,
    ){}
}
```

php getinfo.php :

```
<?php 
  
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // RECIBE EL JSON DE ANGULAR
 
  $params = json_decode($json); // DECODIFICA EL JSON Y LO GUARADA EN LA VARIABLE
  
  require("dbconexion.php"); // IMPORTA EL ARCHIVO CON LA CONEXION A LA DB

  $conexion = conexion(); // CREA LA CONEXION
  
  // REALIZA LA QUERY A LA DB
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE Nick='$params->Nick' AND Pass='$params->Pass'");
 
    class Result {}
    
    // GENERA LOS DATOS DE RESPUESTA
    $response = new Result();
    
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    
        $obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado); 

        $response->resultado = 'OK';
        $response->mensaje = 'LOGIN ALUMNO EXITOSO';
        $response->alumno = json_encode($obj);

    } else {

    $resultado1 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE Nick='$params->Nick' AND Pass='$params->Pass'");

    if($resultado1->num_rows > 0) {
        
    $obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado1); 

        $response->resultado = 'OKEY';
        $response->mensaje = 'LOGIN PROFE EXITOSO';
        $response->alumno = json_encode($obj);

    }else{
    $response->resultado = 'FAIL';
        $response->mensaje = 'LOGIN FALLIDO';
    }
        
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    echo json_encode($response); // MUESTRA EL JSON GENERADO
   
?>
```

Básicamente como veis quiero mostrar lo que me llega de el php asociado con las variables de el objeto.
actualmente solo me pasa la info de esta manera:

[{"Id":"174","Nick":"Rahul","Email":"rmanwanim@gmail.com","Pass":"123","Nombre":"Rahul","Apellidos":"Manwani"}].

y el objetivo es mostrarlo el html, y no hay forma de que solo me enseñe {{ Users.Nick }} o {{ Users.Id}}

Gracias por vuestra atención.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que sea un array con una posición.

```
TS
this.myUsuario = this.Users[0];
html
{ myUsuario.Nick }} o {{ myUsuario.Id}}
```

Espero que te sirva.